# Round Double to 1 decimal place kotlin: from 0.044999 to 0.1

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rounding

I have a Double variable that is `0.0449999` and I would like to round it to 1 decimal place `0.1` .

I am using Kotlin but the Java solution is also helpful.

`val number:Double = 0.0449999`

I tried getting 1 decimal place with these two solutions:

1. `val solution = Math.round(number * 10.0) / 10.0`
2. `val solution = String.format("%.1f", number)`

The problem is that I get 0.0 in both cases because it rounds the number from `0.04` to `0.0`. It doesn't take all decimals and round it.

I would like to obtain 0.1: `0.045 -> 0.05 -> 0.1`

Comment: Why would you expect 0.0449999 to round to 0.1? That is mathematically incorrect.

Comment: It is not incorrect if you round all decimals first: 0.045 -> 0.05 -> 0.1

Comment: Well, that's a pretty meaningless way to round. But, if that's how you want to do it, do it like that: Round to 3 digits, then 2 digits, then 1 digit.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but imagine you have 0.0444999, it would be also wrong. I was wondering if there is a better solution for this.

Comment: Then start at 4, 5, 6, 7 whatever number of digits. It's still not rounding as the vast majority of people would understand it.

Comment: There is no better solution, since this is not a correct way to round numbers. By your logic, I can round $44444.99 to $100000. This is not how rounding works in actuality.

Comment: You're looking for a Ceiling and not a Round

Comment: @Noelia genuinely curious to hear what your use case is for rounding 0.045 -> 0.05 -> 0.1

Comment: @DmitryBrant, Andy Turner, Felipe Andrade, I'm feeling somewhat sorry for Noelia here being repeatedly reprimanded with such ill-informed comments. 

For anyone visiting this page: What Noelia is asking for is called "rounding up", it is not the same as "ceiling" (negative numbers!), whether it is mathematically correct or not is a matter of definition, and most languages I know, including Kotlin and Java, support this rounding mode. It does not take much imagination to think of applications in finance (e.g. a simple piggy-bank saving plan offered by some banks) or in automation.

Comment: @jerry In that case, the question is extremely confusingly phrased and should be rewritten, with perhaps a brief mention of OP's use case for this rounding scheme.  Rounding up to 1 decimal place would mean that 0.000001 would become 0.1.  It's not *at all* clear from the question that this is what OP wants.

Comment: @DmitryBrant After reading again, my apologies, I tend to agree with your statement. Not so much though with your first comment that got an awful lot of upvotes. There can be good reasons for rounding in only one direction, but normally not this way.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

Finally I did what `Andy Turner` suggested, rounded to 3 decimals, then to 2 and then to 1:

**Answer 1:**

```
val number:Double = 0.0449999
val number3digits:Double = String.format("%.3f", number).toDouble()
val number2digits:Double = String.format("%.2f", number3digits).toDouble()
val solution:Double = String.format("%.1f", number2digits).toDouble()
```

**Answer 2:**

```
val number:Double = 0.0449999
val number3digits:Double = Math.round(number * 1000.0) / 1000.0
val number2digits:Double = Math.round(number3digits * 100.0) / 100.0
val solution:Double = Math.round(number2digits * 10.0) / 10.0
```

**Result**:

> 0.045 → 0.05 → 0.1

Note: I know it is not how it should work but sometimes you need to round up taking into account all decimals for some special cases so maybe someone finds this useful.

Comment: One important note to the "Answer 1" it caused my application to crash when i changed language to arabic . the .toDouble() crashed because the number was formatted in arabic (something like this ١٦.٣٤٥٣)

Comment: 1 is risky with localisation

Comment: You can probably save 1000s of crashes here if you update to add DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH)

Answer (score 77):

I know some of the above solutions work perfectly but I want to add another solution that uses ceil and floor concept, which I think is optimized for all the cases.

**If you want the highest value of the 2 digits after decimal use below code.**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal 
import java.math.RoundingMode
import java.text.DecimalFormat
```

here, **1.45678 = 1.46**

```
fun roundOffDecimal(number: Double): Double? {
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.CEILING
    return df.format(number).toDouble()
}
```

**If you want the lowest value of the 2 digits after decimal use below code.**

here, **1.45678 = 1.45**

```
fun roundOffDecimal(number: Double): Double? {
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
    df.roundingMode = RoundingMode.FLOOR
    return df.format(number).toDouble()
}
```

Here a list of all available flags: `CEILING`, `DOWN`, `FLOOR`, `HALF_DOWN`, `HALF_EVEN`, `HALF_UP`, `UNNECESSARY`, `UP`

The detailed information is given in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/RoundingMode)

Comment: what is the import for DecimalFormat? I can't find it

Comment: I have used below import to execute the above methods, hope it helps.

1) import java.math.BigDecimal
2) import java.math.RoundingMode
3) import java.text.DecimalFormat

Comment: I am getting a crash using this. It can cause an issue where to number is formatted as "4,93". Crash: Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException
For input string: "5,79"

Comment: Using this example, beware of locale! I found e.g. portugies which ends up with Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException For input string: "0,1" . In order to prevent this issue use DecimalFormat("#.#", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH))

Comment: Do not use. Exception will happen!

Comment: @WiktorKalinowski could you please share the exception which comes in this code in the logcat, It will help us to solve the issue.

Comment: the examples aren't clear re rounding modes, "HALF_UP" is standard round to nearest (round up if halfway)

Answer (score 62):

The [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) rounding features several [`RoundingMode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)s, including those rounding up (away from zero) or towards positive infinity. If that's what you need, you can perform rounding by calling [`setScale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20java.math.RoundingMode)) as follows:

```
val number = 0.0449999
val rounded = number.toBigDecimal().setScale(1, RoundingMode.UP).toDouble()
println(rounded) // 0.1
```

Note, however, that it works in a way that will also round anything between `0.0` and `0.1` to `0.1` (e.g. `0.00001` → `0.1`).

<sup>The [`.toBigDecimal()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-big-decimal.html) extension is available [since Kotlin 1.2](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#operators-and-conversions-for-biginteger-and-bigdecimal).</sup>

Answer (score 30):

**1. Method (using Noelia's idea):**

You can pass the number of desired decimal places in a string template and make the precision variable this way:

```
fun Number.roundTo(
  numFractionDigits: Int
) = "%.${numFractionDigits}f".format(this, Locale.ENGLISH).toDouble()
```

**2. Method (numeric, no string conversion)**

```
fun Double.roundTo(numFractionDigits: Int): Double {
  val factor = 10.0.pow(numFractionDigits.toDouble())
  return (this * factor).roundToInt() / factor
}
```

<sub>One could create an overload for `Float` as well.</sub>

Answer (score 28):

An example of extension functions for Float and Double, round to n decimal positions.

```
fun Float.roundTo(n : Int) : Float {
    return "%.${n}f".format(this).toFloat()
}

fun Double.roundTo(n : Int) : Double {
    return "%.${n}f".format(this).toDouble()
}
```

Comment: Using this example, beware of locale! I found e.g. portugies which ends up with Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException
For input string: "0,1" . In order to prevent this issue use "%.${n}f".format(Locale.ENGLISH,this).toFloat()

Answer (score 15):

In Kotlin I just use this function:

```
fun roundTheNumber(numInDouble: Double): String {

        return "%.2f".format(numInDouble)

    }
```

Answer (score 13):

**Always beware of Locale!**

With unspecified locale you can get occasional issue (e.g. with Portugies locale) such as

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException
For input string: "0,1"
```

**1. Solution using DecimalFormat approach**

```
fun Float.roundToOneDecimalPlace(): Float {
    val df = DecimalFormat("#.#", DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.ENGLISH)).apply {
        roundingMode = RoundingMode.HALF_UP
    }
    return df.format(this).toFloat()
}
```

**2. Solution using string format approach**

```
fun Float.roundTo(decimalPlaces: Int): Float {
    return "%.${decimalPlaces}f".format(Locale.ENGLISH,this).toFloat()
}
```

Comment: Why not use `Locale.getDefault`?

Comment: @JimOvejera because in formatting you expect a dot in the format. You can be sure English has the dot. But for default locale, when user has for example Portugies locale you get coma in the number so the formatting will fail.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,
its work for me

```
     val number = 0.045
     var filterUserPrice: String? = "%.2f".format(number)
     Log.v("afterRoundoff"," : $filterUserPrice")// its print filterUserPrice is 0.05
```

Answer (score 2):

**For new comers**

Using String.format for decimal precision can lead to problems for different languages.

Use the following code to convert Double to as many decimal places as you want.

```
val price = 6.675668

//to convert to 2 decimal places
totalTime = Math.round(totalTime * 100.0) / 100.00
// totalTime = 6.68

//to convert to 4 decimal places
totalTime = Math.round(totalTime * 10000.0) / 10000.00
// totalTime = 6.6757
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Kotlin Extension Function and then call where you need.

```
fun Double.roundTo(): Double = this.times(100.0).roundToInt() / 100.0
fun Long.roundTo(): Double = this.times(100.0).roundToInt() / 100.0
fun Float.roundTo(): Double = this.times(100.0).roundToInt() / 100.0
```

Example:

```
val amount = 156.26588
val roundAmount = amount.roundTo()
Log.d("Amount:" "$roundAmount") // Amount:156.26
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way for two decimal value return as string

```
private fun getValue(doubleValue: Double): String {
    return String.format(Locale.US, "%.2f", doubleValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want pure Kotlin solution then you can use `roundToInt()` method of Kolin

```
val result = ((number * 1000).roundToInt())/1000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another extension function:

```
fun Number.roundDecimal(digits: Int): Double {
    require(digits >= 0) { "Number of digits must be non-negative." }

    val multiplier = 10.0.pow(digits.toDouble())
    return round(this.toDouble().times(multiplier)) / multiplier
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this extension function:

```
toBigDecimal(MathContext(3, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)).toPlainString()
```