# Round a Number using format not working in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I used `String.format()` to round to the third decimal place. However this didn't work and I solved it using `DecimalFormat`.
Is there anything I implemented wrong?

```
val value = 23.695f
Timber.e("format: ${"%.2f".format(value)}")
```

> **Expect**: 23.70
>
> **Result**: 23.69

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011924/round-double-to-1-decimal-place-kotlin-from-0-044999-to-0-1/49432344

Comment: There is a nice article from the kotlin blog: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places/8843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your string formatting example you're not rounding the number you're just taking the first two decimal places. So your code drops the .005 and keeps the .69

If .70 is the desired result then DecimalFormat sounds correct to me